# Are there any Problems with unclosed sockets

Tags: c++, actionscript-3, sockets, flash

I`m writing a little server programm in C++, client is a Flash AS3 SWF. At the moment I use polling if there is any input from the client. If I would close the client programm, is it possible to send one last message that the programm will close and the server will close too, or is it not and I have to close the server by hand and leave some unclosed sockets. If so, will I get in trouble with these unclosed sockets? I´d be nice if you can give me some solutions/answers for my problem/question

Tanks ins advance

Comment: You will never be 100% sure if this last message is delivered, so you have to deal with opened connections. So you must implement a timeout feature, which disconnects user (closes any sockets and clears everything) after specific amount of time. To prevent closing a live connection - send ping-pong messages between them, which reset the closing timer. Good luck! :)

Comment: I agree with @AndreyPopov, pretty much all socket connections rely on a heartbeat to maintain the connection. If the client is closed intentionally it can send a "goodbye" message, but if the heartbeat stops unexpectedly  (due to, say, the client's computer crashing) you eventually assume the connection is dead.

Comment: Thank you guys, I ´ve already thought about the reset mechanism, but how could I implement the feature, I mean how do I start a timer for example and so on